# Getting Error in Accessing Method from another class

Tags: java, android

I am not able to access `getsongList()` method from another class.
I want to access method in `MainActivity` class from "Songs" class. I tried by following code but i am getting an error. Please check that my code is correct or not.

Help me in fixing the code.

**Songs Class**

```
public class Songs extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<SongModel> songList;
    public void getsongList(){
        //retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new SongModel(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Songs obj1 = new Songs();
        song = obj1.getsongList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making the method static?

Comment: Make func static

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: if i change the method to static , i am getting error in my method. Let me update full code of getsongList method.

Comment: Where does the 'song' variable come from in the 'onCreate' method ? The getsongList method returns nothing (void)

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary I am getting error   .... Incompatible type

Comment: @Aigloun I initialized in MainActivity as private ArrayList<SongModel> song

Comment: @AkshaySharma so your getsongList method should return an ArrayList<SongModel>

Comment: please check the return type of your method void getsongList() i.e. void, so you are assigning a void value to Song class

Comment: You should implement proper fragment interaction instead of creting public methods and call it directly.

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary Thanks ... Problem Solved. But now i am getting another error on running application. Error - Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference in this line ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

Comment: please read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method getsongList()  return void .To access like

song = obj1.getsongList(); you should modify method signature from void to ArrayList and return songlist in that method

```
public void getsongList() 

to 

public ArrayList<SongModel> getsongList() {
return songList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working. But now i am getting another error on running app. Error - Attempt to invoke virtual method on null object reference in this line ------- ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

Answer (score 0):

just try this one time change your method return type void to your arraylit

```
private  songList;
public ArrayList<SongModel> getsongList(){
return song;}
```

**MainActivity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Songs obj1 = new Songs();
  ArrayList<SongModel>  song = obj1.getsongList();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method that return a list, remember to always [programming to interface](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232359/understanding-programming-to-an-interface):

```
private List<SongModel> songList;

public List<SongModel> getsongList() {
  return songList;
}
```

But there is a flaw in the following line:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Songs obj1 = new Songs();

    // You can't call it here!!!!
    song = obj1.getsongList();
  }
}
```

Because Songs it's a **Fragment** (you should also change its name to SongsFragment), it needs times to initialize and creating itself. So you need to add a `Callback` that tell the `MainActivity` when the Fragment finished creating itself.

Please read [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)